# Ways to fast adding missing dependencies with maven?

Tags: maven

I just found out in Eclipse IDE I can right click the project -> Maven -> "add dependency", and I can filter and find dependencies to automatically include in the pom.xml.

Now I wonder if is there any better tool that does just this, but maybe with a better filter on somehow better?

Comment: What kind of filter do you expect? What features are you missing?

Comment: @Fabian actually, the filter only understands the beggining, not the middle, for example, org.apache.something, it won't understant just "something", I need the full name. Also I need to check each import error and look for the proper dependency, some tool could list all import errors and suggest proper dependency...